# Transitioning from Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x: Converting Flux<Part> to MultipartFile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, java-17

I'm in the process of migrating from Spring Boot 2.x to Spring Boot 3.x. In Spring Boot 2.x, I was using **MultipartFile** for file uploads, which worked perfectly. However, with the introduction of WebFlux in Spring Boot 3.x, I've realized that to process multipart data in a streaming fashion, I need to use **Flux** returned from an HttpMessageReader instead of MultipartFile.

Since my code heavily relies on MultipartFile, I'd like to minimize changes to the existing code. Is there a way to convert Flux to MultipartFile seamlessly?

Here's the code for comparison:

With Spring MVC (Spring Boot 2.x):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    // Existing code for Spring MVC
}
```

With Spring WebFlux (Spring Boot 3.x):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) Flux<Part> file) {
    // Updated code for Spring WebFlux
}
```

Is there a way to make this transition with minimal code changes?

Comment: Since you have nocode to begin with it should be pretty easy.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Spring boot. It should be `Transition from Spring MVC to Webflux: convert MultipartFile to Flux<FilePart>`. You could migrate from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 and still use MVC.